# $sum values within array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have a Mongo collection that has this form:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "34210db0-6g91-83e8-ae8c-659f064f503f",
        "dateReceived" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "group" : null,
        "clientShortName" : "My Client Name",
        "sourceShortName" : "Datasource Name",
        "files" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "807061f0-2d77-87e8-8610-9ff3cbc9c774"
                "status" : 1,
                "fileName" : "filename1.csv",
                "numRows" : 15,

            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "587036f0-2n65-55e8-8610-3ee3cbc9c814"
                "status" : 8,
                "fileName" : "filename2.csv",
                "numRows" : 30,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

We have a Mongo query using "find" in conjunction with "map" in order to produce a transformed output. The find/map command looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('batches')
.find({_id: "34210db0-6g91-83e8-ae8c-659f064f503f"}, {"__v": false, "files.diffHistory": false})
.map( doc =>
    {
        doc.id = doc._id;
        doc.clientName = doc.clientShortName;
        doc.dataSourceName = doc.sourceShortName;
        delete doc._id;
        delete doc.clientShortName;
        delete doc.sourceShortName;

        doc.numFiles = NumberInt(doc.files.length);

        doc.files = doc.files.map( file =>
            {
                file.id = file._id;
                delete file._id;
                delete file.__v;
                delete file.edits;

                return file;
            }
        );

        // broken....how should this be formatted?    
        doc.totalNumRows = {$sum: doc.files.numRows};

        return doc;
    }
)
```

This find/map works and produces the expected output EXCEPT for the "totalNumRows" summation.  What we are trying to accomplish is to add up all of the "files.numRows" fields so that we get a single summarised entry at the top level of the returned data set. Ie we'd see a result set that looks like:

```
[
        {
            "id" : "34210db0-6g91-83e8-ae8c-659f064f503f",
            "dateReceived" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "group" : null,
            "clientName" : "My Client Name",
            "dataSourceName" : "Datasource Name",
            "files" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "807061f0-2d77-87e8-8610-9ff3cbc9c774"
                    "status" : 1,
                    "fileName" : "filename1.csv",
                    "numRows" : 15,

                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "587036f0-2n65-55e8-8610-3ee3cbc9c814"
                    "status" : 8,
                    "fileName" : "filename2.csv",
                    "numRows" : 30,
                }
            ],

            "totalNumRows": 45

        }
    ]
```

Everything tried so far produces a broken query. Does anyone know the correct command/format for summing up the "numRows" field of our "file" sub-doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do something better and faster approach then that... Try [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to rename your actual field name and then [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to get total count of `numRows`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id: "34210db0-6g91-83e8-ae8c-659f064f503f" }},
  { "$project": {
    "totalNumRows": {
      "$sum": "$files.numRows"
    },
    "clientName": "$clientShortName",
    "dataSourceName": "$sourceShortName",
    "files": "$files"
  }}
])
```

It will give following output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1111,
    "clientName": "My Client Name",
    "dataSourceName": "Datasource Name",
    "files": [
      {
        "fileName": "filename1.csv",
        "id": 2222,
        "numRows": 15,
        "status": 1
      },
      {
        "fileName": "filename2.csv",
        "id": 3333,
        "numRows": 30,
        "status": 8
      }
    ],
    "totalNumRows": 45
  }
]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly and does appear to be faster under initial load testing. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Gatmando Just a tip... Don't do anything like mapping or looping after query because it is always a time taking task... Always use mongodb `aggregation operators` to do this types things... They are lightning fast...